# Want number value to change to string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a monopoly game in javascript. I am fairly new to javascript so please forgive if I don't state things in a logical way. Anyways, I have a position player counter which tracks the space each player is at( there are 40 spaces total within the game ) . I also have a counter which counts a dice roll and resets every turn ( 1 to 6 ) .Right now the position player counter is just a number from 1 to 40 and obviously this is no good for the user experience and I want this number to represent the name of the space ( park place, marvin gardens, or whatever the name of the space happens to be ) .

I think I have the right idea of the player location being linked to a number between 1 to 40 because logically that makes the most sense to me, but I want to convert this counter number to the name of the space within the game. Obviously this should also update after every dice roll. I'm including a picture to show what I mean. The thing I'm trying to change is in the upper right. [monopoly game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBAQD.jpg)

Once again, I'm sorry that my descriptions may be crude. I have only been studying web design and javascript for a few months and this is my first beginner project and my first post here. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to map the numbers to the names:

```js
var spaceNames = ["Space 1", "Space 2", "Space 3", "Space 4"];
```

Then you can get the names like this:

```js
spaceNames[spaceNumber - 1];
```

The `-1` is needed because Javascript arrays are 0 based, meaning that the first item in an array is `0`. You can read more about that [here](https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/javascript-array-length-always-one-higher).